# Is writing a JavaScript class wherein a single method can both get and set a property bad practice?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I'm writing some classes for a game and I'm not sure if writing a JavaScript class wherein it's methods can be used to set or retrieve one of it's classes members is good practice. I'm trying to understand why or not not.

I've implemented this on jsfiddle already, also posted at:

https://jsfiddle.net/97g16hq3/7/

Specifically, the methods `x(x = null)` and `y(y = null)` are the ones I'm referring to.

```js
class Vector {
    constructor( x, y ) {
    this._x = x
    this._y = y
  }

  x(x = null) {
    if (x) {
        this._x = x
    } else {
        return this._x
    }
  }

  y(y = null) {
    if (y) {
        this._y = y
    } else {
        return this._y
    }
  }

}

const myVec = new Vector( 1, 2 )

console.log(myVec)

// Get the vector
console.log('x: ', myVec.x())
console.log('y: ', myVec.y())

// Set the vector
myVec.x(3)
myVec.y(4)

// Get the vector
console.log('new vector')
console.log('x: ', myVec.x())
console.log('y: ', myVec.y())
```

Comment: If you're asking specifically about getting/setting, then I'd rather use getter/setter properties instead of  standard methods. That way the syntax at the "call" site makes clear what is going on.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I've responded already to your post. Amunium correctly explained to you already what I was going to

Comment: In your current code you can't set `x` to 0 (or to empty string, which is less relevant). You need to use `if (x == null)` to check for `null` or `undefined` and then you can't set `x` to null or undefined (maybe it's ok in your case). Anyway `getX()` and `setX(x)` methods or language built in `get` and `set` functions are more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better go standard and to use [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

Among the other reasons, IDEs are based on standards for many of their helpers (code completion, hints...), so it is better to take advantage of that.

Technically speaking, nothing is wrong with your approach. jQuery uses it extensively: [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/), [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) are just an example.

The library has been there for ages and as far as I know nobody ever spotted any downside about it.

Comment: Not sure I understand your last remark about the `es6 standard` if you could elaborate ? Imo the fact that it is harmless in jQuery is more linked to the fact that it wraps a `mutable` api (the DOM), whereas in the case of OP it would actually make sense for vectors to be immutable.

Comment: The getter/setter overloading of jQuery isn't so bad, but they've done other overloads that were terrible, IMO. Like `.toggle()` being both for events and changing the visible state of elements. Then there's the `$`, which is heavily overloaded to very little benefit over providing sensibly named methods.

Comment: @ziggywiggy "The getter/setter overloading of jQuery isn't so bad" means nothing is wrong with it, which is what the OP is asking. About the rest, of course we can discuss.

Comment: @LucaFagioli: It means it isn't so bad. In other words, some may suggest that such overloading still makes for poor API design. These things are matters of opinion. Some statically typed languages refuse to include method overloading features for this reason, while others are OK with it. But the point of my comment was to ensure that the OP understood that jQuery has examples reasonable overloading (getter/setter), and just really nasty overloading too.

Comment: We can discuss about poor API design (and I agree with you: I do not like it). But I do not find any technical reason to define it a "bad practice".

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking specifically about getting/setting, then I'd rather use getter/setter properties instead of standard methods overloaded with alternate behaior. That way the syntax at the "call" site makes clear what is going on.

```js
class Vector {
    constructor( x, y ) {
    this._x = x
    this._y = y
  }

  get x() {
    return this._x
  }
  set x(x) {
    this._x = x
  }
  get y() {
    return this._y
  }
  set y(y) {
    this._y = y
  }
}

const myVec = new Vector( 1, 2 )

console.log(myVec)

// Get the vector
console.log('x: ', myVec.x)
console.log('y: ', myVec.y)

// Set the vector
myVec.x = 3
myVec.y = 4

// Get the vector
console.log('new vector')
console.log('x: ', myVec.x)
console.log('y: ', myVec.y)
```

In general, I'd avoid that kind of overloaded behavior, especially if the behavior differs wildly. It adds confusion to an API. IMO, the method name should describe what's happening.

Comment: This is a great solution, though I guess I'm not sure it fully answers my question about whether overloading a function like the way in the OP is good practice or not.

Comment: @nootdev: "good practice" is always a matter of opinion. I addressed it more specifically at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: I believe you are correct upon thinking about this a bit more. In this context, native ES functions should be considered the best practice over implementing something different.

Comment: @ziggywiggy _"good practice" is always a matter of opinion_. Not really. Bad practices are meant to avoid performances issues, anti-patterns, and future compliancy problems. You are talking about coding style. Yes I agree, that is a matter of opinion. But here I do not see any bad practice.

Comment: Since the feature exists, and assuming old ES3 support isn't a requirement, I do think so. *However* depending on the side effects introduced by the getter/setters, some would have a valid argument to make that it shouldn't be done. For example, `object.foo = "bar"`, should really do little more than the assignment. If it performed large, slow calculations, or if it had side effects that appeared outside the object, I'd say there would be a good argument for poor design there.

Comment: @LucaFagioli: "Bad practice" is the scarlet letter of programming. It's a stigma attached that allows coders to set aside reason. There have been widely popular notions of "good/bad practice", that were based on little merit. Even when given thoughtful consideration, people can still disagree because different notions of what's ultimately important may drive them.

Comment: Let's be clear: I personally find that approach awful, and I would not use it. I think we found reasonable reasons why using get and set is a better idea, but I would not call it a bad practice, that's what I mean.

Comment: @LucaFagioli: Yep, I wouldn't call it "bad" either, and nor would I use it. "Informed practices" are the best overall, even when the majority may disagree with some of them.

Comment: @ziggywiggy Indeed, this is what the OP was asking for: if it was "bad" or not. I am glad he/she got a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean that you're assigning the value:

```
x(x = null) { // it's default value for x is null
```

So, this sets the argument `x` value to `null` if you pass no value or `undefined`.

Check [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) for reference.

**Edit:**

It matters on your requirement. The following sets the new value if it has value:

```
if (x) {
  this._x = x
} else {
  return this._x
}
```

But this will set the value and doesn't care if it is `null`, `undefined` or anything else:

```
this._x = x // may result in `null`, `undefined`, ...
```

But it's really unnecessary to set the default value for x: `x=null`. Because, you're just checking it with `if(x){`.

In some case, you may particularly check for `null` and in that case setting the default value of x would be a way to go with:

```
if(x===null){
```

Comment: He's not assigning it in that line, no - but look two lines down, and he *is* setting the value. There's nothing wrong with the code, he's just asking if it's good practice.

Comment: @Amunium OP is confused if it is assigning the x like `if(x=3){` assigns x value. But in fact it's not assignment.

Comment: And OP should know if it is good practice or not by using default value `null` rather than `undefined`.  - Primarily opinion.

Comment: No, that's not his question at all, and there's nothing to indicate he's confused about that. It's working fine the way it is. It's a bit unnecessary in Javascript, because you could just test for undefined instead, but there is nothing wrong with it, and you are not answering the question.

Comment: See this statement `Specifically, the methods x(x = null) and y(y = null) are the ones I'm referring to.`

Comment: Yes, the *methods*. Not the lines, the *methods*.

Comment: Hmm,  I'll wait for the response from OP if I'm not satisfying to OP's query or not. But what you're saying is setting the value `this._x=x` is normal behavior. I don't think OP is asking about this at all.

Comment: The OP is asking if it's good practice to overload a single method with different behavior based on the number (or kind) of args passed. They clearly know how the code works already.

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems with this class.

1. Imo. the biggest problem with that code is not this part `x(x = null) {...}` but this one

   ```
   if (x) {
       this._x = x
   } else {
       return this._x
   }
   ```

   Let's start with the most obvious: Is `vector.x(0)` setting the x-value to `0`? What about `vector.x("0")`?

   Then, when you add logic to your function to always cast the argument to a number, what about `NaN, "", [], +[], {}, null and undefined`? And believe me, several of these values will end up there.

   The problem I see here is that your function starts getting a hard time to determine wehther it should set or get the value.
2. Overloading a function means additional logic that has to run, every time the function is called. Generally speaking this is no problem, but here we're talking about the getter and setter for the properties of a Vector in a game engine. This functions will be called thousands of times every frame. This is a considerable performance impact.
3. And this is related to #2. That you use a `class Vector` at all for this. I'd make this as lightweight as possible and simply use literals for this:

   const myVec = { x: 1, y: 2 };

And one tip on the road, your code doesn't contain many `;` you should start using them. Even if the engine inserts them mostly correct, eventually there will be situations where your code doesn't mean what you meant without them.

Comment: Putting aside these issues though, I'm wondering if overloading class methods in this way is good practice or not. Thanks for the #3 tip, I'l be sure to use that.